# Regex : Find any string wrapped in square brackets

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to come up with a regular expression that finds any string that is wrapped in square brackets.
I have a massive document scraped from wikipedia containing many paragraphs like this:

```
"Theology translates into English from the Greek theologia (θεολογία) which derived from Τheos (Θεός), meaning "God," and -logia (-λογία),**[12]** meaning "utterances, sayings, or oracles" (a word related to logos **[λόγος][Citation needed]**".
```

The desired result would be:

```
"Theology translates into English from the Greek theologia (θεολογία) which derived from Τheos (Θεός), meaning "God," and -logia (-λογία), meaning "utterances, sayings, or oracles" (a word related to logos".
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The best suggestion would be to make your question more precise, show us what you have tried so far and do some reading on programming languages and regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are those `**` in the document too? You only mention square brackets.

If they are, the regex would be

```
(\*\*\[.*?\]\*\*)
```

If it's really just the square brackets, then this matches what you're after:

```
(\[.*?\])
```

You don't mention a language, but in Python this would be accomplished by

```
import re

my_re = r'(\*\*\[.*?\]\*\*)'
my_string = '"Theology translates into English from the Greek theologia (θεολογία) which derived from Τheos (Θεός), meaning "God," and -logia (-λογία),**[12]** meaning "utterances, sayings, or oracles" (a word related to logos **[λόγος][Citation needed]**".'
my_corrected_string = re.sub(my_re, '', my_string)

print(my_corrected_string)
```

Comment: Thank you! This exactly what i needed. Sorry for not providing enough information. I used this with JS and it worked perfectly.